# column name space

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, development

I am working on visual studio. I have written a code which updates columns and list in SharePoint programmatically using C#.

But whenever I am creating a column name with a space it is taking as an error `_x0020_`

Suppose I have created work flow so it will not be generated because of space.

Work_x0020_flow
Work flow

What I want is to replace space with `_x0020_`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your string with System.Xml.XmlConvert.DecodeName.

> System.Xml.XmlConvert.DecodeName("Work flow") == Work_x0020_flow